# Im having an issue with emulating or using my xperia z1 with android studio.It says "/dev/kvm is not found"

Tags: android

Im very new to android studio. I cant test an app that I made.
Im having an issue with emulating or using my xperia z1 with android studio.It says "/dev/kvm is not found" I enabled bios virtualization installed intel HAXM. My system is windows 7 32 bit. I used the emulator and the phone in my windows 10 64bit in my desktop in the first try but no luck with my laptop. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the problem...partly... I still cannot emulate on my laptop it gives the same error but when I plug my phone I downloaded a driver from sony's website that I found from android studios list of phone drivers...If anyone has issues they can try that  method...